# Have Apple patented "back tap" feature for mobile devices?

Tags: patentability, apple

**Have Apple patented "back tap" feature for mobile devices?**

One of the coolest features of Apple iPhone, iPad is [back tap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211781). Users are able to enable and associate "double tap" or "triple tap" events with specified actions.

Can this type of features be patented? If yes, I wonder if that feature has been patented by Apple or not. If patented, what is the patent ID?

Comment: Have you tried a google search? Literally the first hit: https://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2021/01/apples-back-tap-patent-also-explores-using-new-voice-recognition-technology-to-control-a-future-tv-by-apple-more.html

Comment: @Eric, I had a Google search and I also went through the article but when I saw the patent pdf I felt they all were discussing about different technology so I wanted to be sure. Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: It's just an application at this point. I just glanced at it and I'm pretty sure this is the one: https://patents.google.com/patent/US20210010797A1/en?oq=20210010797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has applied for a US patent application [US20210010797A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20210010797A1/en?oq=20210010797). It is a lot more technical than you would think. It basically is a way of using interferometry sensors to detect where the vibrations are coming from. Once you know that, it would allow you to detect taps on the back of a phone (for instance). This is only an application and I would expect the claims to be amended before a patent is granted. This [article](https://www.patentlyapple.com/patently-apple/2021/01/apples-back-tap-patent-also-explores-using-new-voice-recognition-technology-to-control-a-future-tv-by-apple-more.html) explains it somewhat.